# package sun.security.krb5 is not visible

Tags: java, kerberos, java-11

I am migrating code to java-11 from the earlier version of java and getting the issue of
`package sun.security.krb5 is not visible`.
I have code like this

```java
Config krb5config = Config.getInstance();
```

Is there any alternative to implement it apart from usinf -add export.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the config, there may be a public API available? You're using a sun package, which isn't supported. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html

Comment: My code is like tyring to get    Config krb5config = Config.getInstance();

          String  Label = krb5config.get(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sun classes for Kerberos, then this is the time to migrate to newer frameworks that support Kerberos.
This is the problem with older JCIFS or even Spring Kerberos, because they use the sun classes directly which are deprecated long back.
Will suggest to do a POC using [Apache Kerby](https://github.com/apache/directory-kerby)